# Circle Not showing up on canvas

Tags: jquery, geometry, jsbin

There is supposed to be a circle on my canvas along with my car and background.

My code is on jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/hagavoyuwu/3/edit

Code for circle that is not working is:

```
function drawcircle(){
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();
}
```

Comment: well you draw over the circle with the picture of your race track and then never draw the circle again...you need to include the drawing of your circle in your draw function...as a matter of fact you see the circle for a split second before it is drawn over by your race track image

Comment: i updated the code as you can see above but the circle is still not coming

Comment: oh nevermind i get what your saying, i got it. Thank you so much for helping me man appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
context.stroke();
```

To the end of the `draw` function